# How to change DataSource from SQL Database in DataGridView so it will be updated

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, datasource

I'm developing an app that interacts with my SQL Database which is encountering problems.

**ATM the problem represents itself inability to change the DataSource parameter in DataGridView before loading child form.**
It is also possible to do it in the main form, but I got no idea on how to do it.
Code of form2(child) is below:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    string pass;   //this is used to pass what user chooses in the Form1 combobox
    public Form2(string choise)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pass = choise;
    }
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pass == "studio")
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = studioBindingSource;
            this.studioTableAdapter.Fill(this.videotekaDataSet.studio);
            MessageBox.Show(pass, "Notification", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
        else if (pass == "star_sln")
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = starslnBindingSource;
            this.star_slnTableAdapter.Fill(this.videotekaDataSet.star_sln);
            MessageBox.Show(pass, "Notification", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
        else if (pass == "movie_star")
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = moviestarBindingSource;
            this.movie_starTableAdapter.Fill(this.videotekaDataSet.movie_star);
            MessageBox.Show(pass, "Notification", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
        else if (pass == "movie_exec")
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = movieexecBindingSource;
            this.movie_execTableAdapter.Fill(this.videotekaDataSet.movie_exec);
            MessageBox.Show(pass, "Notification", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
        else if (pass == "movie")
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = movieBindingSource;
            this.movieTableAdapter.Fill(this.videotekaDataSet.movie);
            MessageBox.Show(pass, "Notification", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
        else MessageBox.Show("Error showing a table", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
}
```

And here goes the SQL query I use

```sql
CREATE DATABASE videoteka
GO
USE videoteka
GO
CREATE TABLE movie_exec (
    certif int PRIMARY KEY,
    name_exec varchar(25),
    adres_exec varchar(50),
    networth decimal(14,0)
)
GO
CREATE TABLE movie_star (
    id_star int PRIMARY KEY,
    name_star varchar(35),
    adres_star varchar(50),
    gender char(1),
    bd_star date
)
GO
CREATE TABLE studio (
    id_studio int PRIMARY KEY,
    name_studio varchar(35),
    adres_studio varchar(50),
    certif int,
    FOREIGN KEY(certif) REFERENCES movie_exec(certif),
)
GO
CREATE TABLE movie (
    id_movie int PRIMARY KEY,
    title_m varchar(40),
    year_m int,
    length_m int,
    incolor char(1),
    id_studio int,
    certif int,
    FOREIGN KEY(certif) REFERENCES movie_exec(certif),
    FOREIGN KEY(id_studio) REFERENCES studio(id_studio)
)
GO
CREATE TABLE star_sln (
    id_movie int,
    id_star int,
    FOREIGN KEY(id_movie) REFERENCES movie(id_movie),
    FOREIGN KEY(id_star) REFERENCES movie_star(id_star)
)
GO
```

*P.S. Sorry for my dumbass code*

Comment: Need to see form1.  You may need to sue an instance of the forl.  See my two form project : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the way I'd structure my program (i'd have a datagridview for each kind of thing [movie/director/star] etc and I'd build them in design time and Show/Hide the relevant one, or put them in a TabPage with a tab for each grid) but:

- Ensure your datagridview1 has its `AutoGenerateColumns` property set to `true`
- After you change the binding on the datagridview1, call `xxxBindingSource.ResetBindings()` on the relevant bindingsource; try it passing false, as technically the schema the bindingsource is looking at, hasn't changed. You might need to pass true if false doesn't work out (it did for me)
- You might need to call `dataGridView1.Columns.Clear()` if you find that the datagridview is generating the new columns on the end of the old ones rather than replacing them
- You don't need the calls that set the dgv1's datasource to null

Comment: i guess, the tabs are more acceptable
but nothing else helped much

Comment: Post your updated code; I wrote a test app for this that swapped out the data sources and it worked fine with my suggestions above.. If we can see your code as it is now, then we can better assist. The answer you posted Below uses a completely different way of doi things (setting the data source of the data grieves to be a data table, not a binding source ) and I really wouldn't recommend it

Answer (score 0):

So I found a way out
the idea is to do it not using the master connection wizard (for the datagridview), but manually insert a connection string and use SqlCommand, SqlDataAdapter and Datatable variables and functions.
**This is what it looks like**

```
MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.Text, "Notification", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
string command = "select * from " + comboBox1.Text;
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(command, co);
adp = new SqlDataAdapter(com); //this is declared globally, so I can use it anywhere
dt = new DataTable();          // same as previous
adp.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Danger dager; this code has some potentially huge security risks. I'd definitely recommend not using it